# Access website through Virtual Machine on host machine

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

**I have the following setup to access the website through the company's VPN:**

I have VM in Virtualbox with Windows 11 running on them. My host is Windows 10. Inside this Win11 VM, I have a VPN client so I am able to connect to a specific site inside the VM.

Is there a way to access this site in the host OS? Some kind of connection with VM so the path will look like this: `Browser -> Host OS -> VM OS -> VPN -> Internet (the website I need to access)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find an answer in the post
[How to share Guest VM's VPN Connection with Host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390615/165358).

The post contains a very detailed answer with screenshots.
It differs from your case in the fact that the host is Linux while
the VM is Windows. There are also multiple VMs that need to also share
the VPN.

Below are the steps for doing that. The Linux part can easily be
applied on a Windows host.

1. Setup a NAT network adapter for your virtualbox guest Windows
2. Setup a host-only network on your host machine
3. Enable the host-only network on your guest virtual machine
4. Start your guest virtual machine
5. Connect to your company's VPN from the guest
6. Share your VPN connection with the host-only network
7. Fix host-only IP settings
8. Try to ping your Windows guest from your Linux host
9. Try to ping a VPN machine from your Linux box
10. Setup your VPN's DNS servers on your Linux host
11. Setup your VPN's routes on your Linux host.

Comment: I got lost in steps 10 and 11... Can you please show me how to do it on Windows Host?

Comment: To find the DNS servers in Windows run in CMD `ipconfig /all` and you'll see it next to "DNS Servers" of the right adapter. Setting them in the host is done in *Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Change adapter options*, right-click the adapter, properties, double-click "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)", in the General tab.